# What should I do if a Moose builder method fails?

Tags: perl, moose

What is the best way to handle a failure in a builder method?

For example:

```
package MyObj;
use Moose;
use IO::File;

has => 'file_name'   ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str',      required   =>1  );
has => 'file_handle' ( is => 'ro', isa => 'IO::File', lazy_build => 1 );

sub _build_file_handle {
    my $self = shift;
    my $fh = IO::File->new( $self->file_name, '<' );

    return $fh;
}
```

If the `_build_file_handle` fails to get a handle, the builder will return `undef`, which fails the type constraint.

I could use a union in the `file_handle` type constraint, so that it will accept an `undef` as a valid value.  But then, the predicate `has_file_handle` will return true, even when the value is `undef`.

Is there a way to signal that the builder failed, and the attribute should remain cleared?

Comment: Why not just throw an exception?

Comment: @friedo, please elaborate on how you would handle exceptions in this case.  My concern is that if I throw a fatal exception in the builder, that means any time I access `file_handle`, I would have to be ready to catch an exception.

Comment: If you don't have an exception you are going to have to check what you return and do something different if it fails - checking for an exception is probably less code.

Comment: The big problem with exceptions is that Perl exceptions suck.  I must have tried 47,000 different libraries, frameworks for exception handling and all have problems.  If you advocate exceptions, I'd like to see how you'd implement them?  With a broken `eval {}; if ($@) {}`  or perhaps with TryCatch?  In another language saying "Throw an exception" means basically one thing and is sound advice.  In Perl, it means opening another whole can of worms.  I haven't tried a module yet that does for Perl exceptions what Moose does for OOP.  Admittedly, I gave up looking a few years ago.

Comment: I think plain old `eval` exceptions work fine in most cases, and I'm also a fan of `Exception::Class`. I'm not sure what Moose has to offer in this area (I once pondered writing a MooseX for exceptions, but the idea was shouted down for reasons that I don't recall.) In any case, maybe it's just not a good idea to lazily build a member that can fail?

Comment: Or, if it can fail, maybe you should force it to be built in BUILD by calling the accessor.

Throwing an exception is the right thing to do, though.  Otherwise your object can be in a meaningless state.

"broken eval" and "TryCatch" aren't your only two options, either.  Try::Tiny is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Best" is subjective, but you'll have to decide which makes more sense in your code:

1. if you can continue on in your code when the filehandle fails to build (i.e. it is a recoverable condition), the builder should return undef and set the type constraint to `'Maybe[IO::File]'`. That means you'll also have to check for definedness on that attribute whenever using it. You could also check if this attribute got built properly in `BUILD`, and choose to take further action at that point (as friedo alluded to in his comment), e.g. calling clear_file_handle if it is undef (since a builder will always assign a value to the attribute, assuming it doesn't die of course).
2. otherwise, let the builder fail, either by explicitly throwing an exception (which you can opt to catch higher up), or simply returning undef and letting the type constraint fail. Either way your code will die; you just get a choice of how it dies and how voluminous the stack trace is. :)

PS. You may also want to look at [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny), which Moose uses internally, and is <strike>basically just a wrapper for</strike>* the `do eval { blah } or die ...` idiom.

*<sub>But done right! and in a cool way! (I seem to hear lots of whispering in my ear from #moose..)</sub>

Comment: I've looked at Try::Tiny.  I've been hesitant to jump on any exception handling module, since I've been burned badly by using previous "wondrous new" class builders and exception handlers.  It took a long time for me to give Moose a chance.

Comment: I don't understand; Try::Tiny is really trivial and does almost nothing beyond what is necessary to work around behavior that is very nearly a bug in Perl.

I get being hesitant to commit to something as far-reaching as Moose, but you can read and understand Try::Tiny's source in about 5 minutes.  What's there to burn you?

Comment: Ether, thanks.  I ended up taking the time to check out Try::Tiny, and it passed a rather thorough sniff test.  When the code is structured properly, it isn't too hard minimize the number of `try{}` blocks.  So far, I am pretty happy with Try::Tiny.

Answer (score 9):

You are not thinking at a high-enough level.  OK, the builder fails.  The attribute remains undefined.  But what do you do about the code that is calling the accessor?  The class' contract indicated that calling the method would always return an IO::File.  But now it's returning undef.  (The contract was `IO::File`, not `Maybe[IO::File]`, right?)

So on the next line of code, the caller is going to die ("Can't call method 'readline' on an undefined value at the_caller.pl line 42."), because it expects your class to follow the contract that it defined.  Failure was not something your class was supposed to do, but now it did.  How can the caller do anything to correct this problem?

If it can handle `undef`, the caller didn't actually need a filehandle to begin with... so why did it ask your object for one?

With that in mind, the only sane solution is to die.  You can't meet the contract you agreed to, and `die` is the only way you can get out of that situation.  So just do that; death is a fact of life.

Now, if you aren't prepared to die when the builder runs, you'll need to change when the code that can fail runs.  You can do it at object-construction time, either by making it non-lazy, or by explicitly vivifying the attribute in BUILD (`BUILD { $self->file_name }`).

A better option is to not expose the file handle to the outside world at all, and instead do something like:

```
# dies when it can't write to the log file
method write_log {
    use autodie ':file'; # you want "say" to die when the disk runs out of space, right?
    my $fh = $self->file_handle;
    say {$fh} $_ for $self->log_messages;
}
```

Now you know when the program is going to die; in `new`, or in `write_log`.  You know because the docs say so.

The second way makes your code a lot cleaner; the consumer doesn't need to know about the implementation of your class, it just needs to know that it can tell it to write some log messages.  Now the caller is not concerned with your implementation details; it just tells the class what it really wanted it to do.

And, dying in `write_log` might even be something you can recover from (in a catch block), whereas "couldn't open this random opaque thing you shouldn't know about anyway" is much harder for the caller to recover from.

Basically, design your code sanely, and exceptions are the only answer.

(I don't get the whole "they are a kludge" anyway.  They work the exact same way in C++ and very similarly in Java and Haskell and every other language.  Is the word `die` really that scary or something?)

Comment: You and others argue persuasively for exceptions.  I was hoping to avoid using them due to the **fact** that they are broken.  Throwing exceptions is easy and works nicely.  Catching them is horrible.  Block `eval` is broken. I've already written enough eval boilerplate to paper the Sistine Chapel.

Comment: Use Try::Tiny, which has been suggested multiple times in multiple threads.  Perl is not going to change because you are afraid of libraries on Stack Overflow.  So either use a library, write the boilerplate, fix perl itself, or go away.

Comment: Having been burned by trying various inside-out techniques (remember that fad) and Error.pm and other try/catch modules, I turned up my nose and did not give Try::Tiny the chance it deserved. Your arguments for exceptions as well as others here led me to the conclusion that they were the correct design.  For that I thank you.

Comment: On a different note, I do not appreciate your habit of rudeness and personal attacks in your response.  Why would an intelligent person choose to use such poor methods of persuasion as straw-man arguments (is die scary?) and personal attacks?  Based on the content of your posts, you are a very intelligent person capable of clear and cogent reasoning. It is unfortunate that you choose to mar your contribution to this forum with persistent rudeness.  Despite your unfortunate tone, I chose to upvote your response and comment, because the actual advice is excellent.

Comment: I don't appreciate your habit of criticizing code without understanding it.  But I answered your question anyway.

If you're nice, I will be nice too.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to signal that the builder failed, and the attribute should remain cleared?

No. This wouldn't make sense, the builder will fire if the attribute is cleaered, if it was cleared within the builder it would just fire when you made the next call to it, and remain in the cleared state. A waste of a lot work, just to *set-something-if-it-works-and-if-not-continue*.

The `type-union` suggestion is a good one but then you have to write code that can function with  two radically different cases: a filehandle, and a non-existant file handle. This seems like a poor idea.

If the file-handle isn't essential to the task then it probably isn't shared amongst the same scope of things with access to the object. If this is the case then the object can just provide a method that generates a filehandle from the object. I do this in production code. Don't get hellbent on making everything a lazy-attribute, some things are functions of attribute and it doesn't always make sense to attach them to the object.

```
sub get_fh {                                                                
  my $self = shift;                                                         

  my $abs_loc = $self->abs_loc;                                             

  if ( !(-e $abs_loc) || -e -z $abs_loc ) {                                 
    $self->error({ msg => "Critical doesn't exist or is totally empty" });  
    die "Will not run this, see above error\n";                             
  }                                                                         

  my $st = File::stat::stat($abs_loc);                                      
  $self->report_datetime( DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $st->mtime ) );    

  my $fh = IO::File->new( $abs_loc, 'r' )                                   
    || die "Can not open $abs_loc : $!\n"                                   
  ;                                                                         

  $fh;                                                                      

}
```

A totally different approach is to subclass `IO::File`, with the meta data about the file you want to keep. Sometimes this is effective, and a great solution:

```
package DM::IO::File::InsideOut;
use feature ':5.10';
use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'IO::File';

my %data;

sub previouslyCreated {
  $data{+shift}->{existed_when_opened}
}

sub originalLoc {
  $data{+shift}->{original_location}
}

sub new {
  my ( $class, @args ) = @_;

  my $exists = -e $args[0] ? 1 : 0;

  my $self = $class->SUPER::new( @args );

  $data{$self} = {
    existed_when_opened => $exists
    , original_location => $args[0]
  };

  $self;

};
```