# What's broken about exceptions in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, exception

A discussion in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164614/what-should-i-do-if-a-moose-builder-method-fails) got me wondering: what do other programming languages' exception systems have that Perl's lacks?

Perl's built-in exceptions are a bit *ad-hoc* in that they were, like the Perl 5 object system, sort-of bolted on as an afterthought, and they overload other keywords (`eval` and `die`) which are not dedicated specifically to exceptions.

The syntax can be a little ugly, compared to languages with builtin try/throw/catch type syntax. I usually do it like this:

```
eval { 
    do_something_that_might_barf();
};

if ( my $err = $@ ) { 
    # handle $err here
}
```

There are several CPAN modules that provide syntactic sugar to add try/catch keywords and to allow the easy declaration of exception class hierarchies and whatnot.

The main problem I see with Perl's exception system is the use of the special global `$@` to hold the current error, rather than a dedicated `catch`-type mechanism that might be safer, from a scope perspective, though I've never personally run into any problems with `$@` getting munged.

Comment: Maybe people who like other programming languages make more mistakes.

Comment: Oh crap, did I just say that out loud? Just kidding!

Comment: Well, other languages have exceptions and Perl doesn't. That's the difference. That we fake them doesn't make Perl really have exceptions.

Comment: @brian, OK, so what makes whatever Perl has *not* exceptions? IOW, what is the definition of an exception and why does `eval`/`die` not meet it?

Comment: You figure out how you want to define exceptions, then we can talk about it. Let's not conflate things built on top of features with actual core features though.

Comment: @brian: Succint and correct, of course, but I think what friedo is getting at is: what are the specific (negative) consequences of having an an-hoc "exception" mechanism rather than having it built into core as it is in other languages, and how severe are the problems thus created?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439966/do-you-use-an-exception-class-in-your-perl-programs-why-or-why-not and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503189/object-oriented-exception-handling-in-perl-is-it-worth-it

Comment: Quoting the OP who said: "The main problem I see with Perl's exception system is the use of the special global $@ to hold the current error", it is worth mentioning there are a few modules that implements exception variable assignment such as `try{ # something } catch( $e ) { # do something with error $e }`. There was TryCatch, but it got broken with version 0.006020 of Devel::Declare and now there is [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) that I developed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some exception classes, e.g. [Error](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Error), cannot handle flow control from within try/catch blocks. This leads to subtle errors:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Error qw(:try);

foreach my $blah (@somelist)
{
    try
    {
        somemethod($blah);
    }
    catch Error with
    {
        my $exception = shift;
        warn "error while processing $blah: " . $exception->stacktrace();
        next;    # bzzt, this will not do what you want it to!!!
    };

    # do more stuff...
}
```

The workaround is to use a state variable and check that outside the try/catch block, which to me looks horribly like stinky n00b code.

Two other "gotchas" in Error (both of which have caused me grief as they are horrible to debug if you haven't run into this before):

```
use strict; use warnings;
try
{
    # do something
}
catch Error with
{
    # handle the exception
}
```

Looks sensible, right? This code compiles, but leads to bizarre and unpredictable errors. The problems are:

1. `use Error qw(:try)` was omitted, so the `try {}...` block will be misparsed (you may or may not see a warning, depending on the rest of your code)
2. missing semicolon after the catch block! Unintuitive as control blocks do not use semicolons, but in fact `try` is a *prototyped method call*.

Oh yeah, that also reminds me that because `try`, `catch` etc are method calls, that means that the call stack within those blocks will not be what you expect. (There's actually two extra stack levels because of an internal call inside Error.pm.) Consequently, I have a few modules full of boilerplate code like this, which just adds clutter:

```
my $errorString;
try
{
    $x->do_something();
    if ($x->failure())
    {
        $errorString = 'some diagnostic string';
        return;     # break out of try block
    }

    do_more_stuff();
}
catch Error with
{
    my $exception = shift;
    $errorString = $exception->text();
}
finally
{
    local $Carp::CarpLevel += 2;
    croak "Could not perform action blah on " . $x->name() . ": " . $errorString if $errorString;
};
```

Comment: All excellent points. Especially the flow-control item. I hadn't considered that one before.

Comment: To the downvoter: I would welcome suggestions for improving this ugly code, it offends me as well. I have switched to TryCatch in subsequent projects, but this post was intended to demonstrate the pitfalls with a particular exception class (and it may extend to others; I haven't tried them all).

Answer (score 25):

The typical method most people have learned to handle exceptions is vulnerable to missing trapped exceptions:

```
eval { some code here };
if( $@ ) {  handle exception here };
```

You can do:

```
eval { some code here; 1 } or do { handle exception here };
```

This protects from missing the exception due to `$@` being clobbered, but it is still vulnerable to losing the value of `$@`.

To be sure you don't clobber an exception, when you do your eval, you have to localize `$@`;

```
eval { local $@; some code here; 1 } or do { handle exception here };
```

This is all subtle breakage, and prevention requires a lot of esoteric boilerplate.

In most cases this isn't a problem.  But I have been burned by exception eating object destructors in real code.  Debugging the issue was awful.

The situation is clearly bad.  Look at all the modules on CPAN built provide decent exception handling.

Overwhelming responses in favor of [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny) combined with the fact that Try::Tiny is not "too clever by half", have convinced me to try it out.  Things like [TryCatch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/TryCatch) and [Exception::Class::TryCatch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Exception::Class::TryCatch),  [Error](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Error), and on and on are too complex for me to trust.  Try::Tiny is a step in the right direction, but I still don't have a lightweight exception class to use.

Answer (score 25):

[Try::Tiny](http://blog.woobling.org/2009/09/trytiny.html) (or modules built on top of it) is the only correct way to deal with exceptions in Perl 5.  The issues involved are subtle, but the linked article explains them in detail.

Here's how to use it:

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    my $code = 'goes here';
    succeed() or die 'with an error';
}
catch {
    say "OH NOES, YOUR PROGRAM HAZ ERROR: $_";
};
```

`eval` and `$@` are moving parts you don't need to concern yourself with.

Some people think this is a kludge, but having read the implementations of other languages (as well as Perl 5), it's no different than any other.  There is just the `$@` moving part that you can get your hand caught in... but as with other pieces of machinery with exposed moving parts... if you don't touch it, it won't rip off your fingers.  So use Try::Tiny and keep your typing speed up ;)

Comment: Note that versions of Perl >= 5.14 now try to keep exceptions sane, so this is no longer the "only correct way".  But it's still pretty good.

Answer (score 9):

A problem I recently encountered with the `eval` exception mechanism has to do with the `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler. I had -- wrongly -- assumed that this handler only gets called when the Perl interpreter is exited through `die()` and wanted to use this handler for logging fatal events. It then turned out that I was logging exceptions in library code as fatal errors which clearly was wrong.

The solution was to check for the state of the `$^S` or `$EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT` variable:

```
use English;
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    if (!$EXCEPTION_BEING_CAUGHT) {
        # fatal logging code here
    }
};
```

The problem I see here is that the `__DIE__` handler is used in two similar but different situations. That `$^S` variable very much looks like a late add-on to me. I don't know if this is really the case, though.

Comment: If the library code is handling an exception using an `eval`, your DIE signal trap will get called -- even if the library code catches and ignores the exception. So it's a good idea for your SIG DIE handler to bow out and not treat it as a real die signal, as you show. You can also just `return`  at the beginning of your signal trap sub if $^S is true. [Perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) describes the state of $^S in various situations. Note that you need `use English;` to use the descriptive variable instead of the cryptic `$^S`.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl, language and user-written exceptions are combined: both set `$@`.  In other languages language exceptions are separate from user-written exceptions and create a completely separate flow.

You can catch the base of user written exceptions.

If there is `My::Exception::one` and `My::Exception::two`

```
if ($@ and $@->isa('My::Exception'))
```

will catch both.

Remember to catch any non-user exceptions with an `else`.

```
elsif ($@)
    {
    print "Other Error $@\n";
    exit;
    }
```

It's also nice to wrap the exception in a sub call the sub to throw it.

Comment: Hi, you seem new here.  Your response doesn't seem to be an answer to the OP (what's broken about Perl exceptions), but a comment about someone else's answer (possibly Dave Kirby's)?  As such, although the information you present is useful in general, since it is not an answer to the OP, so it should have been posted as a comment or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and C#, you can define types that can be thrown, with separate catch blocks that manage each type. Perl type systems have certain niggling issues related to RTTI and inheritance, according from what I read on chomatic's blog.

I'm not sure how other dynamic languages manage exceptions; both C++ and C# are static languages and that bears with it a certain power in the type system.

The *philosophical* problem is that Perl 5 exceptions are bolted on; they aren't built from the start of the language design as something integral to how Perl is written.

Comment: Type constraints are not types.  Perl does not have any issues with types, because it doesn't have any types.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a looong time since I used Perl, so my memory may be fuzzy and/or Perl may have improved, but from what I recall (in comparison with Python, which I use on a daily basis):

1. since exceptions are a late addition, they are not consistently supported in the core libraries

   *(Not true; they are not consistently supported in core libraries because the programmers that wrote those libraries don't like exceptions.)*
2. there is no predefined hierarchy of exceptions - you can't catch a related group of exceptions by catching the base class
3. there is no equivalent of try:... finally:... to define code that will be called regardless of whether an exception was raised or not, e.g. to free up resources.

   *(`finally` in Perl is largely unnecessary -- objects' destructors run immediately after scope exit; not whenever there happens to be memory pressure.  So you can actually deallocate any non-memory resources in your destructor, and it will work sanely.)*
4. (as far as I can tell) you can only throw strings - you can't throw objects that have additional information

   *(Completely false.  `die $object` works just as well as `die $string`.)*
5. you cant get a stack trace showing you where the exception was thrown - in python you get detailed information including the source code for each line in the call stack

   *(False.  `perl -MCarp::Always` and enjoy.)*
6. it is a butt-ugly kludge.

   *(Subjective. It's implemented the same way in Perl as it is everywhere else.  It just uses differently-named keywords.)*

Comment: #5 is not true - see `Carp::cluck()` and `Carp::confess()`, and it's not too much trouble to set a `$SIG{__DIE__}` and `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler with Carp to get stack traces by default. But #7 is extra true, so it evens out.

Comment: Re: #4, you can throw objects since Perl 5.6 at least (most exception systems on CPAN are based on this). I agree that `finally` semantics can get hairy

Comment: #3 - just put this code after eval, or use something like Error.pm or Try::Tiny.

Comment: If you include the main exception handling modules on CPAN (Error::Simple, Try::Tiny, Try::Catch), none of these are true.

Comment: @Ether: Are you sure?  I'm having trouble finding Exception::NotButtUglyKludge on CPAN.

Comment: What was previously #6 was completely false.  Exceptions are thread safe.  Global variables are not shared in Perl.  (And if you use Coro instead, which is a good idea, it manages the globals on a per-coroutine basis.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Exceptions for regular errors. Only Fatal problems that will stop the current execution should die. All other should be handled without `die`.

Example: Parameter validation of called sub: Don't die at the first problem. Check all other parameters and then decide to stop by returning something or warn and correct the faulty parameters and proceed. That do in test or development mode. But possibly `die` in production mode. Let the application decide this.

JPR (my CPAN login)

Greetings from Sögel, Germany